# Can;t make popups closing when user click outside in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have question because i have a problem with JS code on my website. I created 7 popups in Js file and i attached that file to my index.php. When I use all of them only the last is working

index.php (fragment)

```
                            <div id="popupBox_1">
                            <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
                                <div class="popupBoxContent">
                                    <h3>Popup 1</h3>
                                    <p>Obecnie przeglądasz okienko 1</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="popupBox_2">
                            <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
                                <div class="popupBoxContent">
                                    <h3>Popup 2</h3>
                                    <p>Obecnie przeglądasz okienko 2</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="popupBox_3">
                            <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
                                <div class="popupBoxContent">
                                    <h3>Popup 3</h3>
                                    <p>Obecnie przeglądasz okienko 3</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

popup.js (fragment)

```
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == popupBox_1) {
            popupBox_1.style.display = "none";
        }
     }

     window.onclick = function(event) {
         if (event.target == popupBox_2) {
             popupBox_2.style.display = "none";
         }
     }

     window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == popupBox_3) {
            popupBox_3.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

I made these popups and they are working correctly but I created that functions in js because I want to close them when user click outside popup. And it's only working for the last i have defined (I mean popupBox_3) and i want to make them all working!!!

PLEASE I NEED YOUR HELP!

Comment: You aren't binding additional listeners, you're just changing the ``.onclick`` member of the ``window`` object twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign multiple click event handlers using `Node.onclick`, each time you do that you overwrite the last one. You *could* switch to

```
window.addEventListener('click', function() {
   if (event.target == popupBox_1) {
        popupBox_1.style.display = "none";
    }
});

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
   if (event.target == popupBox_2) {
        popupBox_2.style.display = "none";
    }
});

...etc.
```

But it would make a lot more sense to just move all three conditions into one click handler:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == popupBox_1) {
        popupBox_1.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == popupBox_2) {
         popupBox_2.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == popupBox_3) {
        popupBox_3.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, can you tell me what I should put to this function? I mean there where you put "//logic"? I start programming and I'm beginner

Comment: Hi Olivier, no problem. I updated my answer to be more specific